# Overwrite existing Wordpress site on live server from local server

Tags: wordpress, localhost

Still relatively new to Wordpress. I created a basic wordpress site for myself on a local XAMPP server. Using the Duplicator plugin I was able to move my local site to my live host with no problems. From everything I've read so far, the best practice for making changes to your website is to test on your local server and then make those same changes on your live site once you know it won't break anything.

My problem is that I'm planning on making lots of large changes and expanding my site a bit so I really don't want to do everything twice. What is the best way to download my live site back to my local, make my changes, and then upload them back to my live server?

Everything I've searched for in relation to this question is just how to use Duplicator to move your site to somewhere that doesn't already have a site installed, which in this case, I've got versions of the site on both my local and live servers already. Do I need to overwrite? Create a new folder and start over? I can do that on my local side, but not sure how that would work going back to live...

And as far as the database goes, is it better to overwrite or create a new one? I was able to just create everything new on the local side, new /test-site/ folder and new database, but I feel like that will get rather complicated if I try to move it back. Or should I just go ahead and make my changes live and hope everything works correctly and there won't be any issues like a newbie (even though I am a newb)?

I'm using Hostgator Cpanel on the live server side. And Windows 10, XAMPP on the local server.

Any help is greatly appreciated! The more simple directions the better. As well as any advice on workflow to set this type of thing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big deal in editing your live site as long as you know what you're doing and you're keeping backups to date.

Anyway, if you want to go with what you have described above. Again, you don't need to download your live site again and again but make sure you don't do any changes on live site and so that your local site is always ahead of the live.

For me, an easy way is to use the [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin with which you can migrate from local to live within 5 minutes without the need to delete the current site, run the process like Duplicator does.

Comment: Looks like a staging site is what I'm after, which your plugin says it works for that. I'll have to try it.